# running linux on pc. How to use chromium portable?

Tags: linux, chromium, portable

is there a linux version of chromium portable ? the .exe I downloaded from the site is not working with wine. much appreciated if ya can answer this one.

Comment: Did you try to search before asking?

Answer (score 0):

[Chromium Web Browser](https://www.chromium.org/Home) is provided by a package named *chromium-browser* in the default Ubuntu repositories. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install chromium-browser
```

In Debian and Fedora the Chromium web browser package is named *chromium*. To install Chromium in Debian type:

```
sudo apt install chromium chromium-l10n
```

*chromium-l10n* is an optional localization package.

Installing Chromium from your distro's package manager is a legitimate alternative to a nonexistent portable Chromium package for Linux. Search the repositories of your distribution for the Chromium package before you try to build it yourself. Chromium is in the official repositories of Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora, Arch Linux, Gentoo, openSUSE, Mageia, Puppy Linux and Slackware, among others. For instructions about how to build Chromium web browser for other distros see [Checking out and building Chromium on Linux](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_build_instructions.md).